# What are the ListDefinitions XML files used for?

Tags: cme, 2013

I wanted to sort the `users` in the dropdown based on description in `publishing queue popup`. By default its title.

So I came across this post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273228/tridion-2011-how-to-sort-user-list-on-publishing-queue

and it Indeed **solved** my issue.

copying the Answer here:

> Sort users in User dropdown on Publishing Queue popup could be
>   achieved by creating new custom extension. You add new js file to
>   Publishing Queue popup group where you can overwrite
>   `Tridion.Cme.Views.PublishQueue.USER_DROPDOWN_HEAD_PATH` property. It
>   should point to Dropdown xml definition file. You'll need to create
>   your own Dropdown xml definition file (by copying existing
>   `WebUI/Editors/CME/Xml/ListDefinitions/PublishQueueUserDropdown-head.xml`)
>   and add new node `/list:listDefinition/list:rows/list:defaultSortField`
>   with value `@Description`.

Now I have few questions:

1. I can see many other xml files at the same location `WebUI/Editors/CME/Xml/ListDefinitions`, What is the purpose of these xml files in general?
2. What else is possible with these files (just like sorting)?
3. Do we have any schema definition for these xml files that explains more about the Xml Files?

PS: I am not asking it in the original thread on StackOverFlow, because I think it's more suited here now.

Comment: Schemas are stored in [Tridion_home]\web\WebUI\Core\Schemas

Answer (score 6):

These XMLs helpful if you want to do any GUI related task in CME, like if you need to provide client specific GUI for CME.
You can modify font, add additional menu in ribbon of CME, want to place background image etc.

Answer (score 1):

"List Definitions" are XML file that define the headers and column data for lists (and drop-down lists) within the CME and related products.

You are limited in what you can do in them (as they are interpreted by the list controls), but I don't know if there is a definite list of features they support. You can pretty much surmise the features by looking at the existing files, though.